# Relacionar modules con mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Mediante un form subo información de un automóvil, y múltiples imágenes para ese automóvil, tengo los siguientes modelos

El modelo image guarda el nombre de las imágenes que estoy subiendo

```
const ImageSchema = new Schema({
    file_name: String,
});


ImageSchema.virtual('image_name_no_ext').get(function(){
    const no_ext_name = file_name.split('.')[1];
    return no_ext_name;
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Image', ImageSchema);
```

El modelo productInfo guarda el resto de la información

```
const productInfoSchema = new Schema({
    brand: String,
    model: String,
    color: String,
    views: {type: Number, default: 0},
    filename: String,
    fuelType: String,
    doors: Number,
    transmision: String,
    Km: Number,
    description: String,
    image: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Image'}],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('productInfo', productInfoSchema);
```

yo hice la siguiente consulta

```
productInfo.find().populate('image').exec()
.then((res)=>{
    console.log(res);
});
```

lo que quiero es que al hacer la consulta image me muestre todas las imagenes corresponsientes a la info
osea a a info del modelo productInfo, pero al hacer console.log me muestra la  información del producto pero en images donde se supone deberian estar las imagenes no hay nada.

Estoy comenzando con mongoose entonces no tengo mucha idea.

Gracias por la ayuda

```
[
  {
    views: 0,
    image: [],
    _id: 5f9225a49fca9e45a4567a9b,
    brand: 'rrr',
    model: 'rrr',
    color: 'rrr',
    filename: '5a22e7b8-f37f-4f47-b444-9fe567ff09e7',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    views: 0,
    image: [],
    _id: 5f9230301c91a60494d28caf,
    brand: 'e',
    model: 'eee',
    color: 'eee',
    filename: '0635ce9d-4674-4500-8dfc-083767f0fb1b',
    __v: 0
    filename: '5a22e7b8-f37f-4f47-b444-9fe567ff09e7',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    views: 0,
    image: [],
    _id: 5f9230301c91a60494d28caf,
    brand: 'e',
    model: 'eee',
    color: 'eee',
    filename: '0635ce9d-4674-4500-8dfc-083767f0fb1b',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

Asi estoy subiendo las imagenes y la info a los modelos

```
ctrl.uploadImage = async (req, res) => {
    
    const custome_name = uuidv4();
    for(i of req.files){
        const imageTempPath = i.path;
        const ext = path.extname(i.originalname).toLowerCase();
        const targetPath = path.resolve(`public/upload/${custome_name}${ext}`);
        if(ext === '.png' || ext === '.jpg' || ext === '.jpeg' || ext === '.gif'){
            fs.rename(imageTempPath, targetPath, (err) => {
                if(err){
                    throw err;
                }
            });

            //insertamos la imagen en el modelo Imagen
            const newImageurl = custome_name + ext
            const newImage = new Image({
                file_name: newImageurl
            });
            
            newImage.save();

        }
    }  
        //insertamos la info del producto
        const newImageInfo = new productInfo({
            brand: req.body.brand,
            model: req.body.model,
            color: req.body.color,
            filename: custome_name,
        });
        newImageInfo.save();

        res.redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: En tus documents si se está guardando la imagen? Tengo curiosidad de cómo estás guardando la imagen en ese array, podrás compartirlo? Así como lo tienes debería funcionar

Comment: si las imagenes se estan guardando si no que todas las estoy guardando con el mismo nombre osea las imagenes que corresponden al mismo producto [
  {
    _id: 5f92416ce1a4716020bb9e86,
    file_name: 'ea5e6648-de45-4f96-b285-45425c96910b.jpg',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5f92416ce1a4716020bb9e87,
    file_name: 'ea5e6648-de45-4f96-b285-45425c96910b.jpg',
    __v: 0
  }
]no se si sea por eso que no las puedo relacionar

Comment: No tienes que guardar el nombre, tienes que guardar el ID que te regresa mongo. Si no lo tienes es necesario que crees un collection de Images, dónde puedas guardar todos los atributos de la imagen que subiste, esa imagen nueva, te regresará un ID, ese es el que tienes que meter al arreglo, para que mongoose haga el mapeo cuando ejecutes `populate()`

Comment: En tu arreglo de images de tu modelo de `ProductInfo` que estás guardando? el nombre o el ID?

Comment: [
  {
    views: 0,
    image: [],
    _id: 5f92416ce1a4716020bb9e88,
    brand: 'rrrrrrrrrr',
    model: 'rrrrrrrrrr',
    color: 'rrrrrrrrrr',
    filename: 'ea5e6648-de45-4f96-b285-45425c96910b',
    __v: 0
  }
]ahí se guarda el nombre y el id de la imagen

Comment: Añadí la forma en la que estoy subiendo las imágenes

Comment: prácticamente, que es lo que estas guardando en el campo file_name?

Comment: el nombre de la imagen sin extensión, como soy nuevo en bd no relacionales, entonces pensé en  enviar el nombre de la imagen al modelo de la info del producto, y como todas las imágenes tenían ese nombre en el modelo Images mediante una consulta los relaciono, sin embargo veo que no funciona así y que debería usar populate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estas guardando nada en el nodo de `image` de tu modelo de `ProductInfo`, tienes que salvar los ID's que se generan cuando guardas una imagen, y ese mismo ID, pasarlo al arreglo de `image`. Es obvio que no te está trayendo nada por que no estás guardando nada. Te dejo una posible solución, donde se crea un almacenador de ID's de imagenes y luego los planchas al momento de salvar tu modelo de `ProductInfo`. De esa manera cuando hagas el populate verás que ya se hace correctamente

```
ctrl.uploadImage = async (req, res) => {
    
    const custome_name = uuidv4();

    //Creamos un array que nos ayudará a almacenar temporal los ID de las imagenes
    const imgArray = [];
    for(i of req.files) {
        const imageTempPath = i.path;
        const ext = path.extname(i.originalname).toLowerCase();
        const targetPath = path.resolve(`public/upload/${custome_name}${ext}`);
        if(ext === '.png' || ext === '.jpg' || ext === '.jpeg' || ext === '.gif'){
            fs.rename(imageTempPath, targetPath, (err) => {
                if(err){
                    throw err;
                }
            });

            //insertamos la imagen en el modelo Imagen
            const newImageurl = custome_name + ext
            const newImage = new Image({
                file_name: newImageurl
            });
            
            // Utilizamos try/catch para manejar el salvado de la imagen
            try {
                const img = await newImage.save();
                // Agregamos el ID al arreglo dei imagenes
                imgArray.push( img._id );
            } catch( e ){

                console.log( 'Ocurrió un error', e );

            }


        }
    }  
        //insertamos la info del producto
        // Insertamos también dentro de image, el arreglo que obtuvimos antes
        const newImageInfo = new productInfo({
            brand: req.body.brand,
            model: req.body.model,
            color: req.body.color,
            filename: custome_name,
            image: imgArray
        });
        newImageInfo.save();

        res.redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Gracias, voy a probarlo , pensé que se podía relacionar con cualquier propiedad, pero veo que es con el id

Comment: me pareció raro que no mencionaras el desperdicio de crear dos documentos, pudiendo guardar un array de imagenes de en mismo documento

Comment: Lee la documentación de [populate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) The ref option is what tells Mongoose which model to use during population, in our case the Story model. All _ids we store here must be document _ids from the Story model.

Comment: @Enzo creo que quiere tener descentralizada su información, y está bien, le da más organización a la información. No quiero decir que tu propuesta es errónea, pero también tiene que ver con su estrategia digital.

Comment: @alberto A gran escala esto consumiría espacio innecesario en la db, es simplemente una opinión desde el lado de la optimización de recursos